# how to capture and remove text inside an inner parenthesis in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to capture using ruby values inside inner parenthesis from the following string

```
textbeforefirstparantheses( (value = "sdfsdf")   String countryCode, (value = USER.USER_NAME)   final String username,    final String grantType)
```

I want to have

```
textbeforefirstparantheses(  String countryCode, final String username,    final String grantType)
```

I am using following but it will capture everything inside outer parenthesis.

```
\(.*...\)
```

Any help ?

NOTE : capturing the text should also include inner () as shown in expected out put

Comment: Is that a string? Do you mean you want to **remove** the text **and the parentheses** inside the outer parentheses, rather than **capturing** (only) the **text inside** of it?

Comment: please read the question before penalties - capture means "getting text", it doesn't matter what I want to do it after

Comment: "I want to capture using ruby values inside inner parenthesis from the following string"  YES it is a string and I want to capture text inside it

Comment: but in the expected output there isn't an inner paranthesis.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: you know the expected output and input - I am not getting what else you want to answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier not to try to do it in one step. First, match what is inside the outer parentheses, and within the `sub` block, do a secondary match to match the inner parentheses.

The following relies on the assumption that there is only a single pair of outer parentheses so that the greedy quantifier `*` in the outer match will go beyond any inner close-parenthesis.

```
'textbeforefirstparantheses( (value = "sdfsdf")   String countryCode, (value = USER.USER_NAME)   final String username,    final String grantType)'
.sub(/(?<=\().*(?=\))/){|s| s.gsub(/\([^)]*\)/, "")}
# => "textbeforefirstparantheses(    String countryCode,    final String username,    final String grantType)"
```

Comment: excellent! Thanks sawa. All I needed was /\([^)]*\)/ , In one place I have to replace and then scan that in another place. This worked, great!!!

Comment: @AvinashRaj Your `/\(.*?\)/` is less efficient than my `/\([^)]*\)/`.